# What is this subtle difference between the definition of linear dependence for a finite set and for an infinite set?

Tags: linear-algebra

From Terence Tao's Linear Algebra notes:

> We sat that any collection $S$ of vectors in a vector space $V$ are *linearly dependent* if we can find distinct elements $v_1,...,v_n\in S$, and scalars $a_1,...,a_n$, not all equal to zero, such that $$a_1v_1+a_2v_2+...+a_nv_n=0.$$ ... In the case where $S$ is a finite set $S=\{v_1,...,v_n\}$, then $S$ is *linearly dependent* if and only if we can find scalars $a_1,...,a_n$ not all zero such that $$a_1v_1+...+a_nv_n=0.$$ (Why is the same as the previous definition? It's a little subtle).

I can recognize that in the first definition we have only "if ... then ..." whereas the second one is an equivalence "... if and only if ..."

But where does the difference really lie? What is the edge case that makes the first definition not an equivalence?

Comment: Both are supposed to be "if and only if". The difference between the infinite case and the finite case is that, in the infinite case, you pick a finite collection $v_1, \dots, v_n$ from $S$, whereas in the finite case, you use ALL of the $v_i$'s in $S$.

Comment: @KennyWong I don't think that's what Terence meant when he said "*Why is the same as the previous definition? It's a little subtle*"

Comment: Well, if $S = \{ v_1, \dots, v_n \}$ is a finite set, the first definition says that $S$ is linearly dependent iff we can find $a_1, \dots, a_k$ (not all zero) such that $a_1 v_1+ \dots + a_k v_k = 0$ (possibly after renumbering the $v_i$'s). But then, if we set $a_{k+1} = \dots a_n = 0$, we have $a_1 v_1+ \dots + a_n v_n = 0$ too. Or did I miss something?

Comment: @KennyWong It seems to me that you violated the definition when you set $a_{k+1}=...=a_n=0$ "... and scalars $a_1,...,a_n$, *not all equal to zero*..."

Comment: At least one of $a_1, \dots, a_k$ is non-zero. So it doesn't matter that $a_{k+1} , \dots, a_n$ are all zero.

Comment: @KennyWong  Ah, yes, that's correct. But I still don't get why we only have an "if then" in the first definition.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that Tao meant "if and only if". People very often write "if" when they mean "if and only if" in definitions.

Comment: @user442916 The first statement is definition that is why "if" was used. In the second sentence we apply this definition to finite set and now this is already some statement true both in one direction and in another so we must use "if and only if"

Comment: @Minz "if and only if" are also used in definition, "we say that $f$ is a polynomial if and only if ..."

Comment: @user442916, Yes, sometimes but never in statements which are true in both directions

Comment: @user442916, Sorry I ment that  it is sufficient to use "if" in definition in contrast to the statements which are true in both directions

Comment: [this feels insufficient for a full answer, so I leave it as a comment]: Let $V=L^2[-\pi,\pi]$, $S=\{ \sin(kx) \}_{k \ge 1} \cup \{ x\}$. Then $S$ is linearly independent, but there exist constants $c_k$ such that $x = \sum_{k \ge 1} c_k \sin(kx)$ in $V$. This scenario is not a possibility in the case where $S$ is finite.